# Regex matching the pattern with string

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, match

I am implementing a method which need to find if the string corresponds to some pattern :
I am using the following code :

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[\d]{3}00{\d]{4}$"))
{
      return false;
}
return true;
```

And test it with this string `"123003678"`
It returns true...
I can`t figure out what is the problem there...Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the use of brackets is a bit off in your string.

try this:

```
@"^\d{3}00\d{4}$"
```

in your regex example the second bracket starts with a **{** and ends with a **]**, which will screw things up.

Answer (score 1):

you have messed up square bracket with curly braces

Try this

```
^[\d]{3}00[\d]{4}$
```

## [Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/I0IgAiMDx5)

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[\d]{3}00[\d]{4}$"))
{
      return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: If so I don`t understand when I use brackets

Comment: actually square brackets match a character class.